# Angularjs href attribute remove if value is mailto:email

Tags: angularjs

I need to show link in page having attribute value mailto.
normal href attribute value working fine but if value is email than it removed

Code:

```
myCtrl.link = '<code><a href="mailto:sulok@atlogys.com" target="_blank">Email</a></code>';

<code><span ng-bind-html="myCtrl.link"></span></code>
```

rendered output:

```
<code><a target="_blank">Email</a></code>
```

Please suggest how to handle anchor having href value like `mailto:sulok@atlogys.com`

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a "security" issue, 
please have a look at this [doc-page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)...

---

Just say "this is safe" to angular:

```js
function TestCtrl(vm, $sce) {
  'use strict';
  var htmlString = '<code><a href="mailto:sulok@atlogys.com" target="_blank">Email</a></code>';

  vm.link = $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlString);
}

angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', TestCtrl])
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<article ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <code><span ng-bind="link"></span></code>
  </div>
</article>
```